# How to clear angular smart filter upon clicking reset button

Tags: html, angularjs, smart-table

Here I am developing simple angular html form, I am using angular smart table. How can i clear smart table search filter after i click reset button

My html

```
<tr>
  <th></th>
  <th><input st-search="studentId" st-delay="1200" /></th>
  <th><input st-search="studentName" st-delay="1200" /></th>
  <th><filter-options code-id="200" search-field="studentType">
      </filter-options></th>
</tr>

<button id="cm-ResetBtn" name="cm-ResetBtn" type="button" ng-click="Reset()">Reset</button>
```

My angular code

```
$scope.Reset = function () { 
  //TODO
}
```

Comment: You can examine bottom post and it worked for me! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22447374/how-to-trigger-ngclick-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

I guess

JS

```
 $scope.Reset = function () {
        $scope.studentId = '';
        $scope.studentName = '';
}
```

HTML

Need to add `ng-model` attribute to inputs

```
<th><input ng-model="studentId" st-search="studentId" st-delay="1200" /></th>
<th><input ng-model="studentName" st-search="studentName" st-delay="1200" /></th>
```

JSFiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Legendary/538x7avf/1/)

Also you can check this question [Smart Table not update when search filter value changes from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548943/smart-table-not-update-when-search-filter-value-changes-from-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed by `$state.reload()`. That works as expected

Answer (score 0):

You can examine Atkinson's post and it worked for me!

[How to trigger ngClick programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22447374/how-to-trigger-ngclick-programmatically)